# Spherical coordinates of a sphere above the origin

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have to evaluate the volume of the sphere
$$x^2+y^2+(z-2)^{2}=4$$
using spherical coordinates

I found that $0\leq\theta\leq2\pi$ and $\displaystyle0\leq\phi\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$, but I can't get an appropriate interval for $\rho$.

What I thought was: since
$$z-2=\rho\cos\phi$$
and
$$0\leq z\leq4$$ then
$$z-2\leq2\Rightarrow\rho\cos\phi\leq2$$
Therefore
$$0\leq\rho\leq\frac{2}{\cos\phi}$$
Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if you have defined $z-2=\rho\cos\phi$, you have actually violated the standard coordination transformation since the correct transformation from Cartesian to Spherical coordinates is
$$
{x=\rho \sin\theta\cos\phi
\\
y=\rho \sin\theta\sin\phi
\\
z=\rho \cos\theta}
$$
regardless of what problem you manage to solve. The shifted-from-origin sphere then, has the following equivalent representation:
$$
{x^2+y^2+z^2=4z
\\
\rho^2=4\rho\cos\theta
\\
\rho=4\cos\theta\quad,\quad 0\le \theta\le{\pi\over 2}
}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$z = \rho \cos \phi, 0 \leq z \leq 4 \implies 0 \leq \rho \leq 4 \cos \phi$

$0 \leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$